# Subprocess.run Cannot Find File in CMD, but in IDE

Tags: python, subprocess, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to run one line of code in Python that converts a Jupyter Notebook to HTML.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['jupyter', 'nbconvert', '--to','html', r'C:\path\notebook.ipynb'])
```

The code runs perfectly in my IDE. However, when I tried to input the command in Windows Scheduler, it doesn't work.

```
Program/script: C:\path\python.exe
Add arguments (optional): "C:\path\code_above.py"
```

I then opened up CMD and typed in the following code, and got the following message.

```
C:\Users\me> C:\path\python.exe C:\path\code_above.py

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Things I've tried:

Added, removed quotes in "Add arguments"

Ran off cmd.exe first

```
Program/script: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
Add arguments (optional): /c C:\path\python.exe C:\path\code_above.py
```

Looked into my os.environ['COMPSEC'] variable

In the end cmd just can't seem to find my file.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the real `C:\path\code_above.py` have any space characters in it? If so, you may need to enclose it in double-quotes, i.e. `"C:\path\code_above.py"` when passing it as an argument to `python.exe`.

Comment: @martineau no space oops. I shouldve made that clear.

Comment: OK. Then does typing `dir C:\path\code_above.py` at the command prompt work?

Comment: @martineau seems so. In the directory it lists the file along with file size.

Comment: Hmm...what about `dir C:\path\python.exe`?

Comment: @martineau yeah I get that too. I feel like I wouldn't get the error above if its a problem finding python.exe and code_above.py. It's probably the notebook.ipynb that's causing the trouble but even that I can dir to.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to run `subprocess.run` with `shell=True`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['jupyter', 'nbconvert', '--to','html', r'C:\path\notebook.ipynb'], shell=True)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried that already, with the following error code: 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @MapHacks1979 For python3 run `pip3 install jupyter` in your command line.

Comment: pip3 isn't a command for me. I tried pip install jupyter and it's already installed. Using py -3 -mpip install jupyter and it gave me the same thing.

Comment: I ended up finding the answer. I had to add the path to "jupyter.exe" in my code instead of just jupyter, and added an environment path variable to my anaconda3/scripts folder